# Deprecation warning when using createReadStream()

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo-server

I am trying to upload a file to s3 using apollo-server. However, I am getting a deprecation warning `(node:4820) [DEP0135] DeprecationWarning: ReadStream.prototype.open() is deprecated`, despite the method not being marked as deprecated in the NodeJS docs
This is my resolver

```
const { v4: uuid } = require("uuid");
const { extname } = require("path");
const s3 = require("./s3");

module.exports = {
  Mutation: {
    uploadAvatar: async (_, { file }) => {
      const { createReadStream, filename, mimetype, encoding } = await file;
      const payload = createReadStream();

      const { Location } = await s3
        .upload({
          Body: payload,
          Key: `${uuid()}${extname(filename)}`,
          ContentType: mimetype,
        })
        .promise();

      return {
        filename,
        mimetype,
        encoding,
        uri: Location,
      };
    },
  },
};
```

The file object is an argument that is passed to the mutation as a type `Upload`. Below is a definition of the mutation. As for the `creatReadStream()` method, I do not write any other code for it. I just call it in the mutation as it is part of file object

```
type Mutation {
    uploadAvatar(file: Upload!): File
  }
```

Comment: What is `file` in this `const { createReadStream, filename, mimetype, encoding } = await file;`?

Comment: @jfriend00 it is an upload. I have destructured it from the `args` in the resolver

Comment: That's not what I'm asking.  Where does it come from?  Where does `createReadStream` come from?

Comment: @jfriend00 it comes from the file object. When I `console.log(file)`, I get a filename, mimetype, encoding, and the createReadStream method

Comment: Where does the `file` object come from?  That's what I'm asking.  Where is the code that creates the `file` object and where is the code for `createReadStream()`.  I want to look at that code.  The `fs.createReadStream()` that I'm familiar with REQUIRES a first argument that is a path.  So, this is apparently some other `createReadStream()` implementation and I want to know what that implementation is, where is its code, etc..

Comment: The file object is an argument that is passed to the mutation as a type Upload. Below is a definition of the mutation. As for the creatReadStream() method, I do not write any other code for it. I just call it in the mutation as it is part of file object type `Mutation {
    uploadAvatar(file: Upload!): File
  }`

Comment: Ok, if that's the extent of the information you can provide about the origin of the `createReadStream()` function, then I can't help you further.  It's apparently coming from something in your environment, not from the node `fs` module because the node `fs` module does not allow you to call it without an argument.